# SystemExit: 2 : error when calling parse_args()

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I am getting the following error. As I am new to python I don't understand how to solve this error. Thank you in advance.
" usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -i INPUT [-f F]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--input
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2"

This is my code.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", required = True,
                help = 'path to the input data')
parser.add_argument("-f", required=False)

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: `argparse` is not meant to be used in a jupyter notebook.  Where are you getting this code from?

Comment: Do you use one of the required arguments(-i/--input)? How do you call it?

Comment: `parse_args` calls `sys.exit` on argument parsing failure. You can pass `exit_on_error=False` to `ArgumentParser` to substitute this forced exit with an exception.

Comment: `argparse` is meant to handle commandline input for python scripts run from a OS shell (bash, powershell).  Commandline values you provide when stating the `jupyter` server are for the server itself, and aren't passed to the notebook.  Normally you can specify values like this "manually" in a notebook cell.  If you are using some tutorial or other copied code, reread how they intend you to run it.

Comment: Normally when run as a script and you don't provide a required input, `argparse` will issue this usage message and error, and then exit.  In the `notebook`, that error is caught and displayed as this `system-exit 2` with a chance to view the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

-i or --input are required arguments but you don't pass any argument with

> args = vars(parser.parse_args())

Try to add the argument with the folder of the required input data maybe

> args = vars(parser.parse_args("-i /folder"))

Comment: I update my code as per your suggestion.

Comment: If you provide a `sys.argv` substitute, it has to be a list of strings: `parser.parse_args("-i /folder".split())`  or `parser.parse_args(["-i", "/folder"])`.  But I don't think this helps the OP understand what his problem is.  He needs to explain why he's try to use `argparse` in a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try an argparse code in Jupyter-notebook with `required = True`

Be sure to put default value like `default = "your_value"`

In your case it says in help 'path to the input data'

So you need to provide 'path' for your code you are trying to run.

In your case it should be like:

```
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", required = True, default = "/content/your_path",
            help = 'path to the input data')
parser.add_argument("-f", required=False)
```